# Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system

Tags: gcc, cmake, configure

i got this error when using `./bootstrap` command for installing `cmake`

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.18.0, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
```

i checked for gcc and got

```
gcc --version
bash: /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

whereis gcc
gcc: /usr/lib/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

i checked  `cmake_bootstrap.log` file and got

```
./bootstrap: 803: ./bootstrap: /usr/local/bin/gcc-7: not found
Test failed to compile
```

Comment: C++ : Cmake requires a c++ compiler → `sudo apt install g++`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you don't have gcc installed.

In case you specifically need `gcc-7`, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install gcc-7
```

Otherwise you can install the package `gcc` or `build-essential`(which would provide a later version of gcc).

In case this program `bootstrap` wants to have gcc-7 at the specific location `/usr/local/bin/` and that cannot be changed, you can symlink it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/local/bin/gcc-7
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it now and worked i think because of this command "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/local/bin/gcc-7"

Answer (score 3):

By default, new installation of Ubuntu does not have C compiler installed (nor any other tools needed for compiling programs). To install it, you need to install `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```